# package-lock.json is not get downloaded for linked github url

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

I have 2 github project. Let's say one is "mylibrary" and other is "test-project"

I have linked "mylibary" in "test-project" as GitHub URL. So the package.json looks like below.

```
dependencies: {
    "mylibrary": "git+ssh://git@github.com/user/mylibrary.git"
}
```

When I do `npm install`, "mylibrary" is getting downloaded and placed inside "node_modules"

But the clone version of my library doesn't have `package-lock.json`

```
ls node_modules/mylibrary | grep package-lock
```

yields no results

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. From npm [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)

> One key detail about package-lock.json is that it cannot be published, and it will be ignored if found in any place other than the toplevel package.